# Cocos2d-X: CCDrawNode draw circle/custom shape

Tags: android, c++, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am using `CCDrawNode` to create mask type effect (not exactly mask). Everything works well but there is one problem that `CCDrawNode` only draws square and i want to draw it with custom texture/sprite. Is there any solution to it.

Below is my code of using `CCDrawNode`

```
// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

    CCLayer *layer = CCLayer::create();
    CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("HelloWorld.png");
    pSprite->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
    layer->addChild(pSprite, 0);
    addChild(layer);

    //this is the layer that we want to "cut"
    CCLayer* layer1 = CCLayerColor::create(ccc4(122, 144, 0, 255), visibleSize.width, visibleSize.height);

    this->setTouchEnabled(true);

    //we need to create a ccnode, which will be a stencil for ccclipingnode, draw node is a good choice for that
    stencil = CCDrawNode::create();

    //CCClipingNode show the intersection of stencil and theirs children
    CCClippingNode *cliper = CCClippingNode::create(stencil);
    cliper->setInverted(true);
    cliper->addChild(layer1);
    addChild(cliper);

    return true;
}


void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)touches->anyObject();

    // get start & end location
    CCPoint start = touch->getLocationInView();
    CCPoint end = touch->getPreviousLocationInView();

    // get corrected location
    start = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(start);
    end = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(end);

    //stencil->drawDot(start, 25, ccc4f(0, 0, 0, 255));

    stencil->drawSegment(start, end, 25, ccc4f(0, 0, 0, 255));
}
```

Comment: Assuming it's the same class as in cocos2d-iphone then CCDrawNode doesn't draw textures, only (filled) polygons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw custom texture you should use CCRenderTexture. In order to draw something you should go smthin like this

```
myRenderTexture->begin();
mySpriteLoadedWithTexture->visit();
myRenderTexture->end();
```

Also if you want the drawn lines to be smooth you should draw it in loop so that they are placed in equal distance

```
float distance = ccpDistance(start, end);
for (int i = 0; i < distance; i++)
{
    float difx = end.x - start.x;
    float dify = end.y - start.y;
    float delta = (float)i / distance;
    m_brush->setPosition(CCPoint(start.x + (difx * delta), start.y + (dify * delta)));
    m_brush->visit();
}
```

Hope it helps